# How does this problems are solved (modeling/simulation)?

Tags: education, simulations

Can somebody guide me in what to read and learn in order to be able to solve or understand how to solve the following types of problems:

1. The modeling/simulation of the bullet, shot into the water container, at the bottom of which there is a glass cup
2. Automobile crash into the wall/another automobile.

I want to be able to construct the correct mathematical models of such problems. And then to be able to solve them numerically and get the simulation. Of course depending on the problem I will need supercomputer's power, but that is another question.

Comment: As asked this question can't be answered in less than full year university course. That isn't a single, simple *"state[ment] in math form"* of an entire field of endeavor. See also [the Scientific Computation beta site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). But it probably wouldn't be wise to simply re-post this there because it would still suffer from over-breadth and vagueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about Finite Element Methods. For crash dynamics Smooth Particle Dynamics is good.

**Computer codes**

1. [LS-DYNA](http://www.lstc.com/products/ls-dyna)
2. [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.com/)
3. [DEAL.II](http://www.dealii.org/)

**Book**

Physics of Shock Waves and High-Temperature Hydrodynamic Phenomena- Ya. B. Zel'dovich & Yu. P. Raizer

Comment: How about the impact itself, how does it stated in math form? (or in numerical form)

Comment: The method itself does not explain the impact simulation.